# Example of an unbounded sequence whose convergent subsequences converge to same limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, examples-counterexamples

"A bounded sequence of real numbers converges to x if every convergent subsequence of the sequence converges to x."
I require a counterexample to prove that the theorem fails if the hypothesis that the sequence is bounded is dropped.
Also, am I correctly interpreting the question?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It is not clear what you mean with your last sentence: what is the question you are referring to?

Comment: @Hrodelbert My guess is that the OP is asked to show that *the theorem fails if the hypothesis that the sequence is bounded is dropped.* So in the last sequence they are probably asking whether this is the same as finding a sequence with the above properties.(Which is, as far as can say, correct. Perhaps it would be worth adding that unbounded sequence cannot be convergent, to make clear that it is indeed a counterexample.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak I agree that this is the most likely explanation, but without the OP telling us so we cannot be sure.

Comment: Yes. That is what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the trivial example $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ given by $x_n=n$, which obviously does not converge. This sequence has no convergent subsequence, so the condition from the theorem holds vacuously for *any* $x$ (i.e. for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, any convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges to $x$).

Comment: But does an example which is vacuously true suffice?

Comment: Technically yes, since the theorem does not require a converging subsequence to actually exist. At least not explicitly - their existence follows from the boundedness condition, which we are throwing away here.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the sequence $(x_n) \in {}^{\def\N{\mathbf N}\N}\def\R{\mathbf R}\R$ given by 
$$ x_n = \begin{cases} n & \text{if $n$ is even}\\
                       0 & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases} $$
Then every convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges to 0, but $(x_n)$ does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, every unbounded sequence contains a sub-sequence that diverges to plus or minus infinity.

Thus not all sub-sequences can converge to the same value.

Comment: Yes. I know that. But I am talking about a particular case where the subsequences which are convergent converge to dance limit.